# How to create custom content for nginx error 502 page, keep origin url on browser

Tags: nginx

i'm trying to get custom language and message for nginx error page but keep url on browser.. not success
for eg: i go to url : xaluan.com/aaa/bbb.html on the time server down.. nginx will show error 502. with the same url but custom message as my language.

test 1.
I created a custom page at /usr/local/nginx/html/205.html

as following config but it show on web site when error is default nginx error at domain.com/50.html ( the content of webpage not same as i created)

```
error_page 502 /502.html;
location = /502.html {
root /usr/local/nginx/html;
}
```

test 2.
Then i create same page at my www domain folder /home/xaluano/public_html/502.html
but this keep redirect me to root domain.com/502.html the content now same as i created. but.. the url still not as i need

```
error_page 502 /502.html;
location = /502.html {
root /home/xaluano/public_html;
internal;
}
```

**EDIT UPDATE for more detail 10/06/2012**
please download my nginx config http://pastebin.com/7iLD6WQq
and vhost config following: http://pastebin.com/ZZ91KiY6

== *the case test..*

if apache httpd service stop: #service httpd stop

then open browser go to:

*xaluan.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=123456*

I will see the 502 error with the same url on browser address

== *Custome error page*
I need the config which help when apache fail .. will **show the custom message** tell user wail for 1 minute for service back then refress current page with same url ( refresh I can do easy by javascript ), Nginx dosent change url so java-script can work out.

any help will be great.. thank in advance

Comment: nginx doesn't sent an HTTP redirect on 502 errors by default, so you need to find out what is sending that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
location / (
error_page 502 @fallback;
)

location @fallback (
proxy_pass http://backend;
)
```

This will do not change a browser's url

ref: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page

Comment: thanks for help. but where i can put my custom message ? I have read wiki but seem it too hard 2 understand 4 me :(

Comment: @user123862 if your custom 502 page is in http://xaluan.com/502.html, just use it like `proxy_pass http://xaluan.com/502.html`. i can't sure it works but maybe.

Comment: i test with .. proxy_pass http://www.xaluan.com/502.html; but config not even pass the reload of nginx test

Comment: I have update detail config to basebin could you have look. thanks